# Failed to pull existing files from SSH DVC Remote

Tags: dvc

After running `dvc push data.csv` (to ssh-remote), when i try to dvc-pull the same file on another machine from the same remote, it won't get pulled. Below are the logs and the error:

```
2021-01-21 22:17:26,643 DEBUG: checking if 'data.csv'('HashInfo(name='md5', value='279936268f488e1e613f81a537f29055', dir_info=None, size=1458311, nfiles=None)') has changed.
2021-01-21 22:17:26,643 DEBUG: 'data.csv' doesn't exist.
2021-01-21 22:17:26,644 WARNING: Cache 'HashInfo(name='md5', value='279936268f488e1e613f81a537f29055', dir_info=None, size=1458311, nfiles=None)' not found. File 'data.csv' won't be created.
2021-01-21 22:17:26,644 DEBUG: cache '/usr/src/bohr/.dvc/cache/27/9936268f488e1e613f81a537f29055' expected 'HashInfo(name='md5', value='279936268f488e1e613f81a537f29055', dir_info=None, size=1458311, nfiles=None)' actual 'None'
...
2021-01-21 22:17:26,660 ERROR: failed to pull data from the cloud - Checkout failed for following targets:
data.csv
```

However, the file is present on the remote:

```
$ ls -la ~/.dvcstorage/bohr/27/9936268f488e1e613f81a537f29055
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hbabii hbabii 1458311 Jan 22 00:19 /home/hbabii/.dvcstorage/bohr/27/9936268f488e1e613f81a537f29055
```

I double-checked that I am pulling from and pushing to the same remote. I am using DVC v1.11.11.

Could you please give me any hints on what could be wrong?

Cheers, Hlib

Comment: If you run `dvc status -c -r <remote_name>` on the machine you are initially pushing from, does it report any errors?

Comment: @pmrowla, no. Getting `Cache and remote 'ironspeed' are in sync.`

Comment: and just to double check, you can directly `scp` the file (`/home/hbabii/.dvcstorage/bohr/27/9936268f488e1e613f81a537f29055`) from the machine where you are trying to run `dvc pull`?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and for `dvc status -c -r <remote_name>` it shows `Cache and remote 'storage' are in sync.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the problem was that I indeed was pulling from the wrong remote (I had multiple remotes, their configuration was tricky, and local configurations differed on different machines).